# Reference "up" or "down"

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing my text in a large numbered list. I can reference another number by `\label` and `ref`, which gives me the number (which is perfect). But would it be possible to change that to infra/supra (depending on whether the number comes later on in the document or before) + some static text + the number of the referenced `\item`?

So what I would like to make LaTeX print is:

```
\item [text]
\item [text]
\item [text]
\item [text] \label{1}
\item [text]
\item [text]
\item [text] \ref{1} ⇒ supra *static text* 4
\item [text] \ref{2} ⇒ infra *static text* 11
\item [text]
\item [text]
\item [text] \label{2}
\item [text]
```

Comment: Does it matter of it occurs on a different page?

Comment: No, it has to work across the entire document. I reference that number in stead of the pagenemer, as there can be several such numbers on a page

Comment: What does `*static text*` stand for? Is it the same text string in all cross-references? Separately, if I understand your objective correctly, do you want to (a) automatically generate a `\label` instruction for each and every `\item` instruction and (b) prefix the strings "infra" and "supra" to the cross-referencing call-outs depending on whether the item being cross-referenced occurs before or after the current item? Please confirm (or correct).

Comment: No, I will add the `\labels` myself. Every `\label` will be 'inside' an `\item`. A `\ref` should output infra/supra depending on whether the referenced label occurs before or after it, followed by, as you said, a static string (just the same text for every reference) and then the number of the referenced `\item`(not the page number, the number of the `\item`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `etoolbox` you can keep a list of labels that have been defined in the document so far, and display a different string depending on whether a label is in the list or not.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\storelabel}[1]{%
    \label{#1}%
    \listcsgadd{Stored}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\storeref}[1]{%
    \ifinlistcs{#1}{Stored}{supra}{infra} static text \ref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item text
\item text \storelabel{first}
\item text
\item text \storeref{first}
\item text
\item text \storeref{second}
\item text
\item text \storelabel{second}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that two new commands are defined instead of `\label` and `\ref`. If you want, you can also patch the existing commands to include the list processing (see the `etoolbox` manual).

Answer (score 3):

An approach using [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount):

[image]

```
% MWE taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360869/5764
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\storelabel}{\label}
\newcommand{\storeref}[1]{%
  \mbox{}% Not needed if you always have text in an \item
  \ifnum\getrefnumber{#1}<\value{enumi}\relax supra \else infra \fi
  static text \ref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item text
  \item text \storelabel{first}
  \item text
  \item text \storeref{first}
  \item text
  \item text \storeref{second}
  \item text
  \item text \storelabel{second}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

It probably won't work as expected in nested lists. But one can update it to accommodate for that, if needed.