# Auto infra/supra with Linguex examples

Tags: etoolbox, linguex

I'm trying to make this work with `Linguex`:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360869/262813

But I always get "*infra*".

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


% Relative References

\newcommand*{\detectrel}{}


\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\rlabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack%
  \label{#1}%
  \listadd{\detectrel}{#1}%
  \@esphack%
}%

\makeatother


\newcommand*{\supinf}[1]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\detectrel}%
    {\textit{supra}}%
    {\textit{infra}}}%

\newcommand*{\relref}[1]{\ref{#1}~\supinf{#1}}



\begin{document}

See \relref{ex} and \relref{subex}.

\ex. First example. \rlabel{ex}
\a. First subexample. \rlabel{subex}

See \relref{ex} and \relref{subex}.
\vspace{6pt}

More text.
\vspace{6pt}

See \relref{ex} and \relref{subex}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should add the item globally `\listgadd{\detectrel}{#1}%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer, I now know that I should use `\listgadd` in order to give the list a global scope.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


% Relative References

\newcommand*{\detectrel}{}


\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\rlabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack%
  \label{#1}%
  \listgadd{\detectrel}{#1}%  !! Here is the thing, use \listgadd, not \listadd.
  \@esphack%
}%

\makeatother


\newcommand*{\supinf}[1]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\detectrel}%
    {\textit{supra}}%
    {\textit{infra}}}%

\newcommand*{\relref}[1]{\ref{#1}~\supinf{#1}}



\begin{document}

See \relref{ex} and \relref{subex}.

\ex. First example. \rlabel{ex}
\a. First subexample. \rlabel{subex}

See \relref{ex} and \relref{subex}.
\vspace{6pt}

More text.
\vspace{6pt}

See \relref{ex} and \relref{subex}.

\end{document}
```