# macro supra/infra using zlabel

Tags: expl3, zref

I'm trying to make a cross-reference macro. I premise that my technical knowledge of LaTeX is basic ,-)

I adapted the source code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642937/auto-infra-supra-with-linguex-examples)

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\detect@rel}{}
\newcommand*{\rlabel}[1]{%
    \@bsphack%
    \label{#1}%
    \listgadd{\detect@rel}{#1}%
    \@esphack%
}
\newcommand*{\rref@supinf}[1]{%
    \ifinlist{#1}{\detect@rel}{supra}{infra}%
}
\newcommand*{\rref@zcref}[1]{\zcref[ref=page, abbrev]{#1}}
\newcommand*{\rref}[1]{\emph{\rref@supinf{#1}}, \rref@zcref{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}\zlabel{sec1}\rlabel{sec1}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\section{Second Section}
\verb|\rref{sec1}|: \rref{sec1}
\par\medskip
\verb|\rref{sec3}|: \rref{sec3}

\section{Third Section}\zlabel{sec3}\rlabel{sec3}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this code I am forced to use a second personal label -`rlabel`- while I would like to use only `zlabel`.

Also I would like to take advantage of the flexibility of `\NewDocumentCommand` (key/value approach; initial and default options) to have the following `\rref` options:

- passing options from `\zcref` (`ref`, `abbrev`, `note`, etc.);
- a boolean option (`\rref[parent]`) to wrap the command with parentheses;
- initial options: `ref=page`; `abbrev=true`; `parent=true`

I guess `expl3` language is what is needed.

Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do there (as far as I was able to understand from the linked question), but `zref-check` provides means to make this kind of statement in your document. It does not automate the text itself, but allows you to provide it, and checks the position of the label relative to the reference.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-check}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\zlabel{sec1}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second Section}
\verb|\zcref{sec1}|: \zcref[note=supra,check=before]{sec1} % or 'above'
\par\medskip
\verb|\zcref{sec3}|: \zcref[note=infra,check=after]{sec3} % or 'below'
\par\medskip
Warning: \zcref[note=supra,check=before]{sec3}

\section{Third Section}
\zlabel{sec3}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This document will produce a compilation time warning for the third reference, since the label it refers to it is actually "after" it, and we asked to check if it is "before".

```
Package zref-check Warning: Check failed on line 20. Failed check 'before' for
(zref-check)                label 'sec3' on page 1.
```

Pros: no need to redefine anything, you can use the standard label and reference commands with no worries; `zref-check` is well integrated with `zref-clever`. Cons: it is a little less automated than what you were aiming for; you have to write an occasional `note`/`check`, and also pay attention to compilation warnings (at least when you are wrapping up your document).

**Edit:** As it seems nothing short of full automation is desired, I could come up with something which is not great, but hopefully is satisfactory. It works without redefining `\zlabel` (just a hook to it), by counting the labels, and comparing the current state of the counter when the reference is made with a `zref` property which stored the value of the counter when the label was set (perks of `zref`). Now, the options of the package are internal, I personally won't tamper with them to add your requested `parent` option. But you can get the same effect with a couple of reference macros without much loss.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{labelcount}
\AddToHook{cmd/zlabel/before}{\stepcounter{labelcount}}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\zref@newprop{labelcount}{\arabic{labelcount}}
\zref@addprop{main}{labelcount}
\cs_new:Npn \matteo_supinf:n #1
  {
    % \zcref can take multiple labels as argument, but this whole idea
    % presumes only one is being given, so at least we don't typeset
    % supra/infra if there are more labels.
    \int_compare:nNnF { \clist_count:n {#1} } > { 1 }
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF
          { \arabic{labelcount} }
            <
          { \zref@extractdefault {#1} {labelcount} {0} }
          { \emph{infra},~ }
          { \emph{supra},~ }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \matteo_rzcref:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \matteo_supinf:n{#3}
    \bool_if:nTF {#1}
      { \zcref*[ref=page, abbrev, #2]{#3} }
      { \zcref[ref=page, abbrev, #2]{#3} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\rzcref}{ s O{} m }{
  \matteo_rzcref:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rzcrefp}{ s O{} m }{
  (\matteo_rzcref:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3})
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}\zlabel{sec1}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\section{Second Section}
\verb|\rzcref{sec1}|: \rzcref{sec1}, \rzcrefp{sec1}
\par\medskip
\verb|\rzcref{sec3}|: \rzcref{sec3}, \rzcrefp{sec3}

\section{Third Section}\zlabel{sec3}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gustavo, I am familiar with the `zref-check` package. But I would like to automate completely the formatting of the reference (PS: I have clarified the request better)

Comment: Hi @matteo339, I guess I still don't understand what you are trying to do. A wrapper around `\zcref` is not difficult, but I'm not sure it is advisable. However, I don't see how tracking "previous labels" without redefining `\zlabel` is going to be viable. `zref-check` does it, but there's a lot of infrastructure for that, and it only ever compares two labels, not "the current state of the document" with "labels defined so far".

Comment: @matteo339 Besides, `\zcref` can receive multiple labels as argument, and all of the structure you have there seems to presume there's only one. Things can complicate on this side rather quickly.

Comment: @matteo339 I think I could come up with something reasonable. Take a look.

Comment: Your last code responding to my questions perfectly. Thank you very much!  I just have one final request: is it possible to use different localizations term? I have no interest to declaring a different language file. I would like to change some default terms that are active only within the personal macro (e.g. **p.** instead of **pag.**)

Comment: @matteo339 I'd be easy to do so for any type other than page. It'd be a matter of creating a new type (with `\zcRefTypeSetup` or `\zcLanguageSetup` and associate it with the counter with the `countertype` option. For page, not so, since we don't have control of the type. What you could do is, inside the reference macro, make a group (so that changes are local), then make a call to `\zcRefTypeSetup{page}{<your specific setup here>}`.

Comment: @matteo339 Nah, thinking better here. Regardless of the type, you'll need some scoped setup, because, if I understand correctly, you want this personal macro to behave differently from `\zcref`. So in your personal macro, just open a group, call `\zcRefTypeSetup` and/or `\zcsetup` as needed, typeset the reference (as the answer does), and close the group.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this, but I will look into it. In the meantime, thank you very much!