# starred option & setup within a group

Tags: expl3, zref

I would like to modify the following personal cross-reference macro (the initial idea comes from the question: [macro supra/infra using zlabel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670708/macro-supra-infra-using-zlabel)).

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{zref-vario}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{labelcount}
\AddToHook{cmd/zlabel/before}{\stepcounter{labelcount}}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\zref@newprop{labelcount}{\arabic{labelcount}}
\zref@addprop{main}{labelcount}

\cs_new:Npn \suprainfra_text:n #1
  {
    \int_compare:nNnF { \clist_count:n {#1} } > { 1 }
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF
          { \arabic{labelcount} }
            <
          { \zref@extractdefault {#1} {labelcount} {0} }
          { infra }
          { supra }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_zcref_ref:n #1 { \zcref{#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \tl_zcref_page:n #1 { \zvpageref{#1} }
\keys_define:nn {option}
  {
    type .choice: ,
    type / ref .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__option_type_tl {\tl_zcref_ref:n} ,
    type / page .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__option_type_tl {\tl_zcref_page:n} ,
    type .initial:n = page ,
    ref .meta:n     = { type = ref } ,
    ref .value_forbidden:n = true ,
  }

\bool_new:N \l__option_parent_bool
\keys_define:nn {option}
  {
    parent .bool_set:N = \l__option_parent_bool ,
    parent .initial:n = true ,
    noparent .meta:n    = { parent = false } ,
    noparent .value_forbidden:n = true ,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ts_suprainfra_text_type_noparent:nn #1#2
  { \emph { \suprainfra_text:n {#2} }, ~ \l__option_type_tl {#2} }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ts_suprainfra_text_type_parent:nn #1#2
  { ( \ts_suprainfra_text_type_noparent:nn {#1}{#2} ) }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ts_suprainfra:nn #1#2
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn {option} {#1}
      \bool_if:NTF \l__option_parent_bool
        { \ts_suprainfra_text_type_parent:nn {#1}{#2} }
        { \ts_suprainfra_text_type_noparent:nn {#1}{#2} }
    \group_end:
  }
  
\NewDocumentCommand {\supinf} {O{} m}
  { \ts_suprainfra:nn {#1} {#2} }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}\zlabel{sec1}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\section{Second Section}
\verb|\supinf[type=ref]{sec1}|\quad \supinf[type=ref]{sec1}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf[type=page]{sec1}|\quad \supinf[type=page]{sec1}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf{sec3}|\quad \supinf{sec3}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf[ref]{sec3}|\quad \supinf[ref]{sec3}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf[noparent]{sec3}|\quad \supinf[noparent]{sec3}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf[noparent,ref]{sec3}|\quad \supinf[noparent,ref]{sec3}

\section{Third Section}\zlabel{sec3}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]
The macro `\supinf` takes two optional parameters: `type=ref|page` and `parent=true|false`.

`type` parameter call `\zcref` function (by `zref-clever` package) and `\zvpageref` function (by `zref-vario` package).

Now I would like to implement two things that I cannot do independently:

1. a `\supinf*` (starred) version, depending on `\zcref*` and `\zvpageref*`;
2. modify some default terms about italian localization (the changes should only apply within the personal macro), as followed:

   - `zref-clever` italian term:

     - type = chapter

       - name-sg|name-pl = **cap.**
     - type = section

       - name-sg|name-pl = **§**
     - type = page

       - name-sg|name-pl = **p.**
     - type = footnote|endnote|note

       - name-sg|name-pl = **n.**
   - `zref-vario` italian expressions:

     - reftextfaceafter = {\zvhyperlink{p. a fianco}}
     - reftextfacebefore = {\zvhyperlink{p. a fianco}}
     - reftextafter = {\zvhyperlink{p. successiva}}
     - reftextbefore = {\zvhyperlink{p. successiva}}
     - reftextcurrent = {\zvhyperlink{p. corrente}}
     - reftextfaraway = {\zcpageref{#1}}
     - reftextpagerange = {\zcpageref[range]{#1,#2}}
     - reftextlabelrange = {\zcref[range]{#1,#2}}

Finally, I am fully aware that my code does not respect expl3 conventions, but I could not do better :-) I would be grateful if anyone would give me suggestions.

Comment: You still seem to want a macro with custom options. So I'll ask, are you sure? You'd get better results without them, as I suggested in the other question. The reason is because it is hard to *mix* your custom options with those of `\zcref`, so you loose the ability to control `\zcref`. For the sake of having an option that controls a parenthesis wrapping, and such?

Comment: Regarding the question, you still haven't told us what you want "setup within a group". How are we supposed to know? Which terms of the Italian localization you'd like to change?

Comment: Also, the question would probably benefit from a more informative title.

Comment: @gusbrs The macro will have to create a precisely formalized string, so there is no need to have full control over `\zcref` options.

Comment: @gusbrs Regarding the changes about Italian localization, I have modified my question so as to explain better.

Comment: Matteo, I've updated the answer. I'm not sure you'll be fully satisfied, but that's my best shot at the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I think you had a better base in the other answer, by trying to control your customizations with a few variants of the command, instead making them options. Because, there you had full access to the `\zcref` options, as you passed them along to the wrapped call. Here, you'd have to mix them, what you cannot do without hacking the package's internals. Or, lose the ability to pass options to `\zcref`.

Regarding the reference customization to be applied just for this command, you cannot do this "for Italian". In both `zref-clever` and `zref-vario`, language settings are conceived as global, and hence `\zcLanguageSetup` and `\zvLanguageSetup` are preamble only. For `zref-clever` there's `\zcRefTypeSetup` which you can employ within the group of your command for local settings to do this kind of thing. There's however no equivalent for `zref-vario`, which is already a wrapper around `varioref` and `zref-clever`, so there are some limitations to the flexibility it can offer. The only real alternative here would be to declare a new "language" for `zref-clever`, say `supinf-italian`, populate it for both `zref-clever` and `zref-vario`, and then set `\zcsetup{lang=supinf-italian}` within the group of your command. You'd get full flexibility, but it'd be quite some setup for this.

But you seem to want this pretty badly, so there you have one possible version of things:

```tex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-vario}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{labelcount}
\AddToHook{cmd/zlabel/before}{\stepcounter{labelcount}}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\zref@newprop{labelcount}{\arabic{labelcount}}
\zref@addprop{main}{labelcount}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670745/105447
\cs_new:Npn \my_suprainfra_text:n #1
  {
    \int_compare:nNnF { \clist_count:n {#1} } > { 1 }
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF
          { \arabic{labelcount} }
            <
          { \zref@extractdefault {#1} {labelcount} {0} }
          { \emph{infra},~ }
          { \emph{supra},~ }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_supinf:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \group_begin:
    \my_supinf_setup:
    \keys_set:nn { my/supinf } {#2}
    \bool_if:NT \l__my_supinf_parens_bool { ( }
    \my_suprainfra_text:n {#3}
    \bool_if:nTF {#1}
      {
        \bool_if:NTF \l__my_supinf_vario_page_bool
          { \zvpageref*{#3} }
          { \zcref*{#3} }
      }
      {
        \bool_if:NTF \l__my_supinf_vario_page_bool
          { \zvpageref{#3} }
          { \zcref{#3} }
      }
    \bool_if:NT \l__my_supinf_parens_bool { ) }
    \group_end:
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_supinf_setup:
  {
    \zcRefTypeSetup{chapter}
      {
        Name-sg=Cap.,
        Name-pl=Cap.,
        name-sg=cap.,
        name-pl=cap.,
      }
    \zcRefTypeSetup{section}
      {
        Name-sg=§,
        Name-pl=§,
        name-sg=§,
        name-pl=§,
      }
    \zcRefTypeSetup{page}
      {
        Name-sg=P.,
        Name-pl=P.,
        name-sg=p.,
        name-pl=p.,
      }
    \zcRefTypeSetup{footnote}
      {
        Name-sg=N.,
        Name-pl=N.,
        name-sg=n.,
        name-pl=n.,
      }
    \zcRefTypeSetup{endnote}
      {
        Name-sg=N.,
        Name-pl=N.,
        name-sg=n.,
        name-pl=n.,
      }
    \zcRefTypeSetup{note}
      {
        Name-sg=N.,
        Name-pl=N.,
        name-sg=n.,
        name-pl=n.,
      }
  }

\bool_new:N \l__my_supinf_parens_bool
\bool_new:N \l__my_supinf_vario_page_bool
\keys_define:nn { my/supinf }
  {
    type .choice: ,
    type / ref .code:n = { \bool_set_false:N \l__my_supinf_vario_page_bool } ,
    type / page .code:n = { \bool_set_true:N \l__my_supinf_vario_page_bool } ,
    type .initial:n = page ,
    ref .meta:n = { type = ref } ,
    ref .value_forbidden:n = true ,
    parens .bool_set:N = \l__my_supinf_parens_bool ,
    parens .initial:n = true ,
    noparens .meta:n    = { parens = false } ,
    noparens .value_forbidden:n = true ,
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\supinf}{ s O{} m }{
  \my_supinf:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}\zlabel{sec1}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\section{Second Section}
\verb|\supinf[type=ref]{sec1}|\quad \supinf[type=ref]{sec1}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf[type=page]{sec1}|\quad \supinf[type=page]{sec1}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf{sec3}|\quad \supinf{sec3}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf[ref]{sec3}|\quad \supinf[ref]{sec3}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf[noparens]{sec3}|\quad \supinf[noparens]{sec3}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf[noparens,ref]{sec3}|\quad \supinf[noparens,ref]{sec3}
\par\medskip
\verb|\supinf*{sec3}|\quad \supinf*{sec3}

\section{Third Section}\zlabel{sec3}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have declared the pseudo "italianSupinf" language, so everything works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It would be great if it were possible to set the pseudo-language automatically via babel/polyglossia, so that if the document language is 'x' then the pseudo-language would be set as \zcsetup{lang=xSupinf}

Comment: @matteo339 Mhm, I don't think that would be possible. How would `babel` or `polyglossia` know that "italianSupinf" even exists? You are clearly stretching the intended use case of the functionality, as I think you are well aware. Do note that this "independent" behavior of the `lang` option is what at this point I think was an ill advised decision of my past self which, if I find a good way to get rid of in the future, I may seize it.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I was thinking something like 1) language set in babel/polyglossia (e.g. italian) 2) macro that generates the pseudo-language name (e.g. italianSupinf) 3) pseudo-language set via macro \zcsetup{lang=\macro}. All this automation would be convenient to be able to use different pseudo-languages, without intervening within the tex code

Comment: @matteo339 "macro that generates the pseudo-language name". No way, sorry.  ;-) As mentioned, you are stretching the intended use case of a "language" in so doing.

Comment: Okay, I understand your point of view. The "forced" use of the `lang` option has been useful to my very particular scope. I think it is not necessary to delete the option because of me ;-) See you soon

Comment: @matteo339 Not "because of you", of course. But, as I told you, it is actually in my "wish list" to follow `babel` and `polyglossia` in this regard. It's the standard, and would simplify option handling significantly.